# How to add background text in CCombobox

Tags: c++, mfc, ccombobox

We often see a background text on search bars i.e. "Search Here", "Type here to search" etc. and it disappears when we start typing. Have a look at the following one:

[image: A sample of what I need]

Is there any `built-in` method to implement the same functionality in an `MFC Application` for the [CComboBox Control](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/12h9x0ch.aspx) ?

Answer (score 3):

Use [CComboBox::SetCueBanner](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb385230.aspx)

This sends window message `CB_SETCUEBANNER`. `SetCueBanner` is also available for `CEdit`. This feature needs at least Windows Vista.

This function is unicode only, it has to have to unicode text.

If you are targeting WinXP, `SetCueBanner` is not available and the program will not compile. But you can still send `CB_SETCUEBANNER` (`0x1703`) message:

```
::SendMessageW(myComboBox->m_hWnd, CB_SETCUEBANNER, 0, (LPARAM)L"Text");
```

This will compile and run on all systems, however it won't have any effect in Windows XP.

Comment: It seems helpful but I am amazed that `SetCueBannar` is not available in the methods list of `CComboBox`, All that I got is `error C2039: 'SetCueBanner' : is not a member of 'CComboBox'` What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: Probably you are targeting WinXP. You can still use use this function through WinAPI message (see updated answer)

Comment: Thanks for the update sir, but I am using `Windows 8.1 Enterprise`

Comment: You are working on Windows 8.1, but you are targeting your app for WinXP. Try the `SendMessageW` option.

Comment: `SendMessageW` gave me the error `0xC000041D: An unhandled exception was encountered during a user callback.`

Comment: @ItbanSaeed: [CComboBox::SetCueBanner](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb385230.aspx): *"This method is supported in Windows Vista and later. Additional requirements for this method are described in [Build Requirements for Windows Vista Common Controls](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb531404.aspx)."* Check your project to see what platform you are targeting.

Comment: I have no idea why `SendMessage` would cause `0xC000041D` error here. If you don't have a combo box with ID = `IDC_COMBO1` then it results in unhandled exception and crash. Try `myComboBox->m_hWnd` instead of `GetDlgItem`

Comment: Late to the party, but perhaps @ItbanSaeed was using a multibyte character set. I had this issue and changing to unicode fixed it..

Comment: @aquirdturtle yes, `CB_SETCUEBANNER` is Unicode only, it doesn't have ANSI version unlike many other Windows APIs

Comment: myComboBox->SendMessage(CB_SETCUEBANNER, 0, (LPARAM) L"Text");